# Phrase for "Thinking that something is not going to happen, then act in a way that causes that thing not to happen"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

It's on the tip of my tongue -- I want to refer to a person who believes that A is not going to happen, and therefore acts in a way that ends up preventing A from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Self-fulfilling prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy) I believe is what you're looking for!

Or, if you're thinking of it more intentionally, maybe [self-sabotage(-ing)](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/basics/self-sabotage)?

Comment: Wow you're fast! And yes, self-fulfilling prophecy is exactly what I'm looking for!